# Load QIcon from base64 string

Tags: c++, qt, base64

Is it possible to create a [QIcon](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qicon.html) from a base64 string?

I see we can load base64 strings into a [QByteArray](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qbytearray.html#fromBase64).
And I see we can create a QIcon from a QPixMap.

Using that, I have tried the following:

```cpp
const QByteArray data = QByteArray::fromBase64("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");

QImage image;
image.loadFromData(data, "PNG");

QPixmap pixmap;
pixmap.fromImage(image);

QIcon icon(pixmap);

QPushButton* button = new QPushButton(this);
button->setIcon(icon);
```

It's not showing anything.

PS: you can try the base64 image [here](https://base64.guru/converter/decode/file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for `QImage`, though: you can create the pixmap directly from the byte array

```
QPixmap pixmap;
pixmap.loadFromData(data);
```

Comment: Indeed. Same outcome with less code; that's got to be better, surely?

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
QPixmap pixmap; 
pixmap.fromImage(image);
```

with

```
QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(image);
```

This is static function that returns new pixmap.

Comment: You can also skip creating QIcon explicitly, and pass QPixmap to `setIcon`. It will be implicitly converted to QIcon.

Comment: You'd expect both to do the same going by name alone, but apparently not. Thanks!